# Where can I find the gray linen texture that's used as the Lion login screen background?

Tags: graphics, login

My company just updated to Lion, and I really like the gray linen texture that's used as the initial login screen background. I'd like to use it for my desktop background, but it's not one of the options in the Desktop preferences (in the Apple section, anyway.) I'm assuming the graphic exists somewhere, and if I know where I can choose it from the folders.

Can anyone tell me where this graphic is saved or what its filename is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dark linen source file is stored in the System Library folder so you will need "root" or administrator permissions to make changes to the directory or the file.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png
```

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Buried it rather nicely... I wonder why. And strangely, it won't let me copy it to another directory.

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why they set strange permissions on a .png file.

Comment: Because it's a PNG file in /System/Library/Frameworks/

Comment: OK, I can understand not allowing the file to be deleted or changed, but it wouldn't even let me copy it.

Comment: You can copy it with `cp` directly from Terminal.app.

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to it. You just need to tell the OS you want to use that as your Desktop image. I'll explain how in a separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open System Preferences » Desktop and Screen Saver:
2. Click the "+" at the bottom left:
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the "Go To Folder" menu, and paste in the path to the background image:

   ```
   /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png
   ```

   (Press Go, and then <kbd>Return</kbd>  when you see the NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png file is selected)
4. You will now be back at the System Preferences window. Make sure that the drop-down selector is set to 'Tile'

Voilà!

Comment: Your images are now broken. Do you think that you could fix them please?